Solution for Allowing SaaS Users to Connect to Data Sources and Query Data
I'm working on a SaaS platform where users need to connect to various data sources (BigQuery, S3, MySQL, and others) and be able to query their data directly. I’ve looked into some solutions but haven’t found the ideal approach that combines flexible data connections with querying capabilities.
Here’s what I've considered so far:

ODBC: While it supports multiple data sources and querying, there are several drawbacks:
Most ODBC solutions are not open-source and tend to be expensive.
Few connectors are available for popular APIs (like Shopify, Salesforce, etc.).
Connections lack native, easy-to-manage authentication and are generally complex to implement. Each connection requires installing ODBC drivers, which is cumbersome.

ETL Solutions (e.g., Airbyte): These can connect to various sources but only support data transfer to a destination. They don't allow real-time querying of the data.


Ideally, I'm looking for an open-source solution that: Supports real-time querying of connected data sources. Provides native or easy-to-configure authentication options. Can connect to both traditional databases and API-based data sources.
Has anyone found an effective way to combine data source connection and querying in a way that’s SaaS-friendly and real-time? Any recommendations for tools or architectures that could handle this?
